# Как вызвать actionStop из views Yii2

Tags: yii2

я новичёк в программировании. Разбираю сейчас проект на Yii2, подскажите пожалуйста каким образом я могу вызвать экшен контроллера из views по нажатию кнопки, никаких данных я не передаю, мне нужно просто действие. кнопка не в виджете.
В каком направление мне копать помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: через ajax или просто ссылка? на клиенте имя-контроллера/имя-метода пишутся через чёрточку. Например, `MyInterestingHouseContoller::actionThisIsMyAction` во вьюъе будет написано как `/my-interesting-house/this-is-my-action`

Comment: мне наверное ссылка не подходит, мне на экшен не надо переходить мне нужно что бы он выполнил действие а страница осталась на месте

Comment: тоже самое только ajax